# Batch file FOR loop improvements

Tags: windows, for-loop, batch-file

We've got code in productions, that checks file attributes (result of `check.bat file1.bin` returns 0 or 1) and restart user processes if necessary (if returned 1, then restart process). Code is working fine, but I just wanted to ask is there a way to improve it with FOR loop, since we really do the same thing every cycle, but with +1 to username, task name and filename

```
@echo off

:cycle1
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`check.bat file1.bin`) DO (SET var=%%F )
if %var% == 1 (taskkill /f /fi "USERNAME eq user1" & SCHTASKS /RUN /TN "task1")
goto cycle2

:cycle2
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`check.bat file2.bin`) DO (SET var=%%F )
if %var% == 1 (taskkill /f /fi "USERNAME eq user2" & SCHTASKS /RUN /TN "task2") 
goto cycle3

:cycle3
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`check.bat file3.bin`) DO (SET var=%%F )
if %var% == 1 (taskkill /f /fi "USERNAME eq user3" & SCHTASKS /RUN /TN "task3") 
goto eof

:eof
exit /b 0
```

Comment: Do you want to increment the numbers indefinitely, or just loop through the numbers 1 through 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `for /l` loop to increment file numbers. I also made some other small changes to make the code simpler, no need for those code blocks:

```
@echo off
for /l %%a in (1,1,3) do for /F "delims=" %%F IN ('check.bat "file%%a.bin"') do (
    if %%F equ 1 taskkill /f /fi "USERNAME eq user%%a" & SCHTASKS /RUN /TN "task%%a"
)
```

However, I am sure your users and tasks are not called `user1,2,3` and `task,1,2,3` so you need to define your user and task variables and still use the number increments to select each use according to the `bin` file number:

```
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "u1=Steven"
set "u2=Maddy"
set "u3=Dan"
set "t1=taskname1"
set "t2=taskname2"
set "t3=taskname3"
for /l %%a in (1,1,3) do for /F "delims=" %%F IN ('check.bat "file%%a.bin"') do (
    if %%F equ 1 taskkill /f /fi "USERNAME eq !u%%a!" & SCHTASKS /RUN /TN "!t%%a!"
)
```

Comment: yet I has not tested the code but it seems to me to be a solution. thank you, @Gerhard!